# Sending Public Get Requests to a Flask API hosted on an ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, flask, amazon-ec2

I transferred a Flask api that is linked to a tensorflow model to an ec2 instance. I show the ec2 instance is correctly hosting the api, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what http address to send my get requests to. I have tried both an elastic IP, public IP, and Private IP all provided by aws. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the Flask app listening on the correct port?

Comment: More details need how did you know that EC2 instance is correctly hosting the API? Did you try to call the API locally using curl and loopback IP?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a security group configuration issue.
Make sure that the security group which is connected to the instance has an inbound rule to allow the incoming traffic to your api (protocol, port, IP range).
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html